# Making CSS Responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, responsive

There is a component MainPage.js and inside that there is a SideBar.js component.
I want SideBar to acquire full width when max-width is 500px. How to achieve that?
I have provided the code for both MainPage and Sidebar components and their scss files.

**MainPage.js**

```
const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="main-page">
       <Modal click={click} closeModal={closeModal} />
      <SideBar />
      <div className="main-content">
    </div>
</div>
  );
};
```

**mainPage.scss**

```
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 664px;


    .main-content {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 16px;
        // flex: 5;
        background-color: white !important;
        border-radius: 20px;
        flex-direction: column;
        @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
            width: 0%;
        }

     
}
```

**SideBar.js**

```
const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="side-bar">
        <div className="list-container">
          <ul>
            <li>
             
            </li>
            <li>
           
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <QuizOutlinedIcon /> My Library
            </li>
            <hr />

            <li>
           
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

**
sideBar.scss**

````
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    width: 140px;
    height: 100vh;
    // flex: 0.3;
    padding: 16px 20px 20px 30px;
    top: 2px;

    /* Mobile Styles */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        width: 40%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list-container {

        width: 90px;
        height: 361px;
        display: flex;
        gap: 16px;

        ul {
           
                }

            }
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: I see that you have already used media queries which should be the way to handle this.
Can you explain what's not working currently?
Also, have you posted the complete scss file, no class/selector is specified at the start of these files

Comment: set your mainpage width to 100%, child can't take 100% width if the mainpage doesn't have 100%

Comment: @Phil I tried setting the width:100% , still not working

Comment: @IshitaAmod why is your `.listcontainer` has width 90px, have you tried removing that

Comment: @IshitaAmod everything is working as expected, i don't find anything wrong in your style https://wpyd3k.csb.app/